# displaying save file dialog in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I'm going to display a save file dialog in my asp.net web page, user clicks a button and a save file dialog appears which allows user to save a report in CSV format in his hard disk, how can I do it? is it possible to display save file dialog in ASP.NET?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, you'll want to create a whole new page (or, better, *.ashx handler) to serve up the CSV results.  The button should post a GET request to this page.  When it receives the request, in either the ProcessRequest() method (for a handler) or the Page_Load() method (for a Page), you will have code like this:

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
Response.AddHeader( "Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"report.csv\"" );
// write your CSV data to Response.OutputStream here
Response.End();
```