# Save dialogue box in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Showing Save file dialog box in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12351415/showing-save-file-dialog-box-in-asp-net)

Currently, In my website, users are able to download file from my website with option to open/save file.
In addition to that I want to display save dialogue box which will allow user to save file to specific location on his local machine. How can I do that?

Comment: I have done that but i want to allow user to select specified location to save the file on their local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allowing a user to select where to download the file is a browser setting and not something you can specify in code.

In my experience, browsers default to automatically save to a location such as the user's "Downloads" folder (I always seem to have to change this option myself after a fresh install of a given browser).